# How to run .jar on Spark on Hortonworks VM?

Tags: java, hadoop, virtual-machine, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm new to Hortonworks VM and I got confused. I'm trying to run a .jar file on Spark. Normally I test locally on Windows by running

`spark-submit --driver-memory 4g --class en.name.ClassName %CODE%/target/program.jar`

but since I need Hive, I thought I'd move to a Hortonworks VM to test locally. Now, I've uploaded my .jar and the input files to the HDFS (to the `/tmp/my_code` directory) via Hortonworks' Ambari's HDFS Files GUI. What next? I also found the command line, but how do I access my .jar on the HDFS from the VM's command line? I'm trying to run

`spark-submit --driver-memory 4g --class en.name.ClassName /tmp/my_code/program.jar` 
from the sandbox condole (the one running on `http://127.0.0.1:4200/` by default, `root@sandbox` "Shell in a Box"), which is not working. It says the .jar does not exists. How can I point the VM to use the .jar on HDFS? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAR should be on local file system NOT in `hdfs`. Only input file should be in `hdfs`. so `/tmp/my_code/program.jar` path should be local, and that why you are seeing that error: `the .jar does not exists`

if you run-this command:

```
>spark-submit --help
```

you will see:

```
 --jars JARS   Comma-separated list of local jars to include on the driver
               and executor classpaths.
```

*update:*
Accroding to [Documentations](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/submitting-applications.html):

> application-jar: Path to a bundled jar including your application and
>   all dependencies. The URL must be globally visible inside of your
>   cluster, for instance, an hdfs:// path or a file:// path that is
>   present on all nodes.

so,

***if jar is on hdfs:***

`spark-submit --driver-memory 4g --class en.name.ClassName hdfs://target/program.jar`

***if jar is on local:***

`spark-submit --driver-memory 4g --class en.name.ClassName /target/program.jar`

*OR*

`spark-submit --driver-memory 4g --class en.name.ClassName file://target/program.jar`

Comment: Hmm. Okay, I'll try this. In this case, how do I specify the path to the files on Hadoop in my code? So, I read it like `DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().json("?path?");`, what goes into `?path?`? How do I specify to read from HDFS? Do i just put `hdfs://tmp/my_data/*.json`?

Comment: yes you can use `hdfs:/` or `/tmp/my_data/*.json` for hdfs input file. for using local input file you must specify `file:/` but I think in case for hdfs file you don't need `hdfs:/` in path but it is a good practice to use it.